# Is there a way to theme LibreOffice to match the elementary design guidelines?

Tags: software-installation, office, design

I think I read somewhere that some adjustment was possible, making LibreOffice fit in reasonably well with the rest of the system, but I can't find it anymore.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The folks from Xubuntu are currently working on an [elementary icon theme for LibreOffice in Github](https://github.com/shimmerproject/libreoffice-style-elementary)

Answer (score 4):

I'd suggest the sifr theme. Use this command:

```
sudo apt-get install libreoffice-gnome libreoffice-gtk libreoffice-style-sifr libreoffice-gtk3
```

[From reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/elementaryos/comments/2wnar5/theming_of_libreoffice_skype_and_other_popular/).

---

However, a lot of people suggest customising the crystal theme.

> ```
> sudo apt-get install libreoffice-style-crystal
> ```
>
> Type ‘Y’, and press enter to complete.
>
> Now, download the Faenza theme [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/35272968/elementaryupdate/images_crystal.zip).
>
> Now, after downloading Faenza theme (Don’t worry about it being called images_crystal.zip – it’s the Faenza package, but it’s just been renamed to save you having to do so) you will need to obtain ‘Root Access‘ to be able to modify themes. So, into a Terminal copy and paste, or type out the following:
>
> ```
> sudo -i pantheon-files /usr/share/libreoffice/share/config
> ```
>
> Next, remove, or rename the `images_crystal.zip` for in case anything goes wrong. I renamed it to `images_crystal_old.zip`. Doing this ensures you have a fall-back should anything go wrong.
>
> Now, simply transfer your new `images_crystal.zip` over to your Files window, and all being well, it should have appeared.
>
> Now, fire-up LibreOffice, and go to `Tools — Options — View`, and change the theme to Crystal.

[Source](http://web.archive.org/web/20131128085508/http://oselementaryluna.wordpress.com/2013/08/21/libreoffice-convert-the-ui-to-elementary-luna-beauty)

Comment: Thanks, I'll give this a try and accept the answer if it works for me :)

Comment: I upvoted but had to accept Daniel's answer since it's the official (albeit still upcoming) solution.

Comment: @waldyrious yeah, that's fine I'd do the same!